# When setting JSON.stringify value equal to variable it adds '\' to the front and \' to the end

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I'm sure that I'm missing something fundamental, but I am not sure what.

Here is some code:

```
  var carColor = JSON.stringify(this.car.color);

  document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = carColor; // displays: "blue"
  console.log(carColor); // displays: '\'blue\''
```

I assume I can use a function to remove the slashes from that text, but is there a better way to get that variable to just be equal to the color name?

Comment: That may just be the way some `console.log` implementations represent a string with quote characters. Try using `alert` and see if they're actually in the string.

Comment: What is the value of `this.car.color`?

Comment: @JeremyBanks - thanks! Looks like you're right about that

Comment: @Jasen it is "blue" in this example. I am just trying to get that value and then use it in a switch statement

Comment: @JeremyBanks if you make that an answer I'll happily mark this as answered. Thanks for replying!

Comment: @NealJones Done; I'm happy to have been of assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of `JSON.stringify()` is standardized and does not add the slashes you are observing.

However, the precise behaviour of `console.log()` is not standardized across platforms, and can vary. A proposed specification is in development, but that's still in its very early stages (and it's still not clear to me whether it will cover this detail). You cannot rely on its output being entirely consistent.

On some platforms, strings may be automatically re-escaped before they're displayed, so that any special characters are clear to the reader (who is assumed to be a developer, not an end user who would be confused). When the string has already been escaped with `JSON.stringify()`, this double-escaping can results in backslashes being shown in the output, as you've experienced.

You can use another method of displaying text such as `alert()` to verify the actual contents of your string.

Answer (score 2):

The '\' is a delimiter to allow using reserved characters in a string.

A complete list can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp

Essentially, If I had a string like this:
`'He said 'hi!''`, javascript would interpret this as the string `'he said '` then attempt to execute the code `hi!` and encounter an issue.  To tell javascript that you want to put a single quote inside of a string, you need to write `\'`  So this string would now become `'He said \'hi!\''`

In your case you have a `color` variable is assigned the string `'blue'`.  JSON is designed to ship objects around, so typically you'd have a JSON string `'color: \'blue\''`.  Since only the value is being JSONified, it becomes the string `'blue'`, which contains the '`'` and would be written `'\'blue\''`.  Hope that helps!